# How can I create SDF-Icon's (used in Mapbox) from PNG?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, glyphicons

My task is to change the icon-color of an icon-image in Mapbox. The only way mapbox allow to do this is by using sdf-icons(https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-symbol-icon-color).

By Hour's of searching i couldn't found the easiest way to achieve this. There is an npm module I found is https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-sdf but after using its command on a png to convert it into sdf and then rendering on a map is not giving me finest results.

The command I am using

```
image-sdf cycle-initial.png --spread 5 --downscale 1 --color black > cycle.png
```

cycle-initial.png(INPUT) is below:

[image]

cycle.png(OUTPUT) is below:

[image]

But while using the cycle.png as an Image src is not giving the finest results.

[image]

Code snippet:

```
const img = new Image();
img.addEventListener('load', () => {
            this.mapInstance.addImage('circle-icon', img, { sdf: true });
        }, false);
img.src = cycle;
```

I request if anyone, please help me if I am doing anything wrong here, or is there any correct way to create sdf-icon to render correctly.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

After days of research, I think i found the solution. Also, I want to sum-up creation steps of SDF icon's.

First, thing first what is **SDF** in simple words:
SDF is a raster format that is optimised for displaying resized, recoloured, and rotated raster images. They are single color.

**Usage:**
This is my first interaction with SDF in MAPBOX.

Reason is we cannot change the color of icon(if svg or normal raster png) in symbol layer, you have to provide SDF(specialised png) format in order to achieve it.(https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-symbol-icon-color)

**How to create?**

1. Npm module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-sdf
   Command:

```
image-sdf input.png --spread 10 --downscale 1 --color black > output.png
```

2. Imagemagick:  https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php . ImageMagick allows you to do this with one command:

```
convert in.png -filter Jinc -resize 400% -threshold 30% \( +clone -negate -morphology Distance Euclidean -level 50%,-50% \) -morphology Distance Euclidean -compose Plus -composite -level 45%,55% -resize 25% out.png
```

***UPDATE***

3. There is also third way of achieving this by using older [tag](https://github.com/mapbox/maki/tree/v0.5.0) of Maki Library, Where there is only one JS file [sdf-render.js](https://github.com/mapbox/maki/blob/v0.5.0/sdf-render.js) can convert your source svg to sdf icon.
   But please note that this Tag(v0.5.0) is using Older version of JSDOM which is not supported now, To execute this file you have to convert the code of this file using svgdom and @svgdotjs/svg.js modules.

More Detail's:
[Box is appearing around Icons in Mapbox on sdf = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63650484/box-is-appearing-around-icons-in-mapbox-on-sdf-true)

**What i was doing wrong?**

Answer: Before executing the image-sdf command on a png(Please note: it has to be black & white raster path). Resize(Increase) it to around 40-50%.

Like in my case, I resized the normal raster png and the result's were amazing. Have a look.
(Please note: I didn't change a word in code and used the same image-sdf command)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for spending the time to share what you learnt!

Comment: Super helpful question & answer, thanks. Faced with the same issue, after LOTS of fiddling with the image-sdf parameters and the mapbox style specification parameters, I wasn't able to find a good resolution-size compromise. I did find a little hack though, I made the size right, and then added a 1px halo in the same color as the icon. This outline helped keep the details of the icon.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to share my own experiences generating SDF symbol images for Mapbox.

First I tried the npm module `image-sdf`, but it seems buggy. The values in the generated SDF don't transition smoothly across edges in the input image. (See [this example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WLbc.png), which shows the input on the left, and the output from `image-sdf -s 3` on the right. In a correctly generated SDF, the outline of the cross shape should not be perceptible at all.)

Next I tried @Dolly's ImageMagick solution. However, the command Dolly provided didn't generate the precise format needed by Mapbox.

- Mapbox seems to only read the alpha channel of the PNG, so we need to append extra commands to copy the data to the alpha channel.
- Dolly's solution generates SDFs where the pixel value of 128 acts as a "zero point" or threshold – pixels outside the shape have a value less than 128, while pixels within the shape have a value greater than 128. However, Mapbox appears to use 192 as its threshold. I confirmed this by inspecting some of the font glyph SDFs stored inside Mapbox's internal state, as well as [looking inside Mapbox's (delightfully uncommented) GLSL files](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/937f67f321f5419c0e82e78e262553330e59c8bd/src/shaders/symbol_sdf.fragment.glsl#L36).

The following ImageMagick command line takes these issues into account:

`convert in.png -filter Jinc -resize 400% -threshold 30% \( +clone -negate -morphology Distance Euclidean -level 50%,-50% \) -morphology Distance Euclidean -compose Plus -composite -level 45%,55% -resize 25% -alpha copy -fill black -colorize 100 -channel alpha -fx "a+0.25" out.png`

The output is [delightful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fClvq.png).

Note that the input image should be a **pure bitmask** - the symbol itself in white, all other pixels black, with no antialiasing (no grays).

I hope this is useful to somebody!

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to explore is giving your image a size. I wanted to use an svg for my marker image, and changing:

```
let img = new Image();
//to
let img = new Image(256, 256);
```

Gave much better results-

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add another answer to this question, with the added benefit of being completely open-source and browser based: https://jobtalle.com/SDFMaker/.

[SDF Maker screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzK8r.png)

You can upload a png or svg image and download a sdf-enabled png on the spot.

These are the reasons I prefer this approach:

- no need for installing external tools, 100% browser based
- works with black icons on a transparent background (easier to find or with less preprocessing than the white icons on a white background described in the other answers)
- open source

Something that additionally improved my resulting sdf icon was adding some padding around the icon to get rid of some strange border-related effects. This was easy to do on the following website: https://www.svgrepo.com/, where you can edit every icon before downloading it ([SVG Repo vector editing screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL2sj.png)).