# Add icon halo as border around image uploaded as a Mapbox icon

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a mapbox map with custom coffee mug icons (not maki icons). I want to give the icons a halo conditionally based on a data field of each point. This works, but since the icon is uploaded as a png, it gets treated as a rectangle, even though the image is of a coffee mug which is mostly round. So when you add a halo, it gets added around the perimeter of the bounding rectangle of the icon. Here's a picture of two of these icons, one that has a halo because it meets the "CONDITION" and one that doesn't.

[image: Map showing regular icon and icon with halo box]

How can I make this halo wrap around the border of the coffee mug icons, like it does for maki icons? Here is the relevant part of my style definition:

```
layout: {
  'icon-image': 'cafe-icon'
},
paint: {
  "icon-color": "#1a7a08",
  "icon-halo-color": "#e4be8b",
  "icon-halo-width": ['case', ['==', ['get', 'CONDITION'], true], 4, 0]
}
```

Also, here are the mapbox dependencies in my package.json file:

```
"@mapbox/mapbox-sdk": "^0.12.1",
"mapbox-gl": "^2.1.1",
"@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^4.7.0"
```

And here is the coffee mug icon I'm using for now:

[image: coffee mug icons]

Comment: Which Mapbox-gl version Are u using? Also Could you attach your alternate dummy png file in the description, So that we can check locally?

Comment: @Dolly thanks, I updated the question.

Comment: I believe one of the main issues here was that I didn't leave enough empty space around the mug icon in the image. At smaller size renderings on the map, the number of pixels I assigned to the halo exceeded this space, causing the whole box of the image to fill with the halo color all the way to the corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Mapbox-gl-js documentation couple of style properties can only be applied to [SDF Enabled Images](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/using-recolorable-images-in-mapbox-maps/#what-are-signed-distance-fields-sdf) and one of them is "icon-halo-width" also.

*[READ HERE](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/using-recolorable-images-in-mapbox-maps/#using-sdf-enabled-images)*

Which says:

> Four style specification properties can only be used with SDF-enabled images: icon-color, icon-halo-color, icon-halo-width, and icon-halo-blur.

I downloaded a demo png of "shop-15.png" from this link and applied the icon-halo-width to 10 and style get applied.

Code:

```
//downloaded 
var accessible = "http://localhost:3000/shop-15.png";

map.loadImage(accessible, function (error, image) {
                if (error) throw error;
                map.addImage('accessible', image, { sdf: true });
                map.addLayer({
                    "id": "iconLayer",
                    "type": "symbol",
                    "source": 'maine',
                    "layout": {
                        'icon-allow-overlap': true,
                        "icon-image": "accessible",
                        "icon-size": 3,
                    },
                    "paint": {
                        "icon-color": "white",
                        "icon-halo-color": "red",
                        "icon-halo-width": 10
                    }
                });
            });
```

Screenshot:

[image]

How To Create SDF Images?

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63299999/how-can-i-create-sdf-icons-used-in-mapbox-from-png/63314688#63314688) is the link where I combined few of my research.

Thanks!